# Find the distribution function $F(y)$

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

Can someone show me how to do this problem?

> $$\begin{array}{c|ccc}
> y&1&2&3&4\\
> \hline
> p(y)&.4&.3&.2&.1
> \end{array}$$
>
> **a** Give the distribution, $F(y)$. Be sure to specify the value of $F(y)$ for all $y$, $-\infty<y<\infty$.
>
> **b** Sketch the distribution function given in part (a).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asked to find the **cumulative** distribution function $F(y)$ of the random variable $Y$. By definition,
$$F(y)=\Pr(Y\le y).$$ 
So $F(y)$ is the total "weight" (probability) **at or to the left of** $y$.

Let's start. If $y\lt 1$, then $F(y)=\Pr(Y\le y)=0$. For if $y\lt 1$, there is $0$ total "weight" (probability) at or to the left of $y$. For example, $\Pr(Y\le 0.7)=0$. In the notation the problem seems to encourage, $F(y)=0$ for $-\infty\lt y\lt 1$, or equivalently $F(y)=0$ in the interval $(-\infty,1)$.

But there **is** some non-zero weight **at** $1$. If $y=1$, indeed if $1\le y\lt 2$, we have $F(y)=\Pr(Y\le y)=0.4$. So $F(y)$ "jumps" to $0.4$ at $1$, and stays there over the whole interval $[1,2)$.

There is another jump at $2$. If $y=2$, indeed if $2\le y\lt 3$, then $\Pr(Y\le y)=0.4+0.3=0.7$. Continue.